# Sed entire word with when replacing single letters, with BSD sed?

Tags: sed, osx, bsd

I think  I found some GNU solutions but I need BSD `sed` solutions.

What I want to do is replace the entire word at once. If the word is "clayii", and my code is `sed 's/c/k/g;s/l/i/g;s/a/e/g;s/y/i/g;s/k/o/g'`, I want it do produce "kieii", but it produces "oieiii" for obvious reasons. On the last section, it searches for `k` and finds it in the beginning, but if it searched the whole word, it would never do that.

Obviously, "clayii" will be different all the time, I want it to replace individual letters, but not start from the beginning, if it has already replaced the first `n` and then finds on in the beginning it should not start over. So basically ignore what's been replaced already, if that's detectable.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: use `-E` and don't worry about BSD sed.

Comment: this may seem obvious but if you don't want `sed` to replace individual letters, then don't tell it to do that.  either search and replace entire words, or restrict the s/// command to operate only on matching words.

Comment: @cas I don't think you understand, I want it to replace individual letters, but  not start from the beginning, if it has already replaced the first four it should not start over.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use `y//` (sed's built-in tr command) insteaad of `s///`:

```
$ echo clayii | sed -e '/clayii/ y/clayk/kieio/'
kieiii
```

Note that the `y//` command will still apply to the entire line, not just to the matching word.

Comment: Where do I put all the letters? It can be up two 200 letters. I don't see how the command works similar to `sed 's/c/k/g;s/l/i/g;s/a/e/g;s/y/i/g;s/k/o/g'` at all?

Comment: if your solution involves 200 search-and-replace commands for individual letters (how do you have that many different letters anyway?) then you probably ought to rethink the problem.

Comment: I have accented and umlauted letters. It adds up.

Comment: regardless of the number of letters, I still think this sounds like an XY problem (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).  What is it that you are actually trying to do?

Comment: I know what an XY problem is, I don't think is one. It's nothing important, I just wanted to scramble words but choose exactly which letter turns into another letter, I didn't think when I first wrote the script, but it's starts replacing things that are already replaced when it matches them. But like I said, it's nothing important.

Comment: Well, of course it's going to replace letters that have already been replaced - you're telling it to do exactly that with the `/g` (global) modifier.  Which is why i suggested using `y//` instead - it works exactly the same as `tr`, replacing matching letters in the first group with the letter in the same position in the second group.

Comment: see Glenn Jackman's answer at http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/246750/7696 for a perl solution to this.

Comment: `y///` gives me the exact same out put.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  `y//` runs once over the entire input.  Your series of `s///g` commands  runs one after the other in sequence.  First changing all `c`s to `k`s, then `l` to `i` then `a` to `e` then `y` to `i` and finally `k` to `o` (thus changing all the `k`s that used to be `c`).

Answer (score 0):

With BSD sed, you can use:

```
sed "s/[[:<:]]clayii[[:>:]]/kieii/g" /path/to/file
```

Comment: Where Do I put  all the letters though? As you can see in my question, I wanted it to be like `'s/c/k/g;s/l/i/g;s/a/e/g;s/y/i/g;s/k/o/g'` which means c becomes K, l becomes i, a becomes e and y becomes i. I don't see how that fits into your command.

Comment: Sorry; I misread the question and thought it was about word boundaries in BSD `sed`, which comes up from time to time.  It sounds like you're looking for something like `tr` or sed's `y//`.

Answer (score 0):

you can loop over it:

```sh
echo  here is a pat and a tern and a pattern     |
sed  -e'1{H;x;s/\(.\).*/\1pattern\1replace/;x;}' \
-eG  -e'/\(.*\)\(.*\n\)\(\n\1\)\n/!{P;d;}'       \
     -e's//\3\2/;t-'                             \
-e:- -e's/\(\n\)\(.\)\(.*\n\)\(.\)/\4\1\3/;t-'   \
     -e's/\n//;P;d'
```

---

```
here is a pat and a tern and a replace
```

That does the replacement char by char progressing left to right. It shifts the first delimiter to the right of the replaced character for each substitution. You can see what I mean if you stick a `l`ook command in just before the loop `t`ested substitution after `-e:-`:

---

```
here is a pat and a tern and a \npattern\nreplace$
here is a pat and a tern and a r\nattern\neplace$
here is a pat and a tern and a re\nttern\nplace$
here is a pat and a tern and a rep\ntern\nlace$
here is a pat and a tern and a repl\nern\nace$
here is a pat and a tern and a repla\nrn\nce$
here is a pat and a tern and a replac\nn\ne$
here is a pat and a tern and a replace\n\n$
here is a pat and a tern and a replace
```

If you really are looking for a sort of translation thing, you can do that, too. I wrote this earlier as an answer to another question:

> It looks doable - you just have to sort of shift-in/shift-out:
>
> ```sh
> echo can ccccc ccccccccclayii sed clay ignore \
>      every cclayii thing but the matching word\
>      - cclayiicclayii |
> sed     -e'y/ /\n/' \
> -eh     -e's/\(cclayii\)\1*/ & /g;x;s// /g;s/^/ /' \
> -ex     -e's//./;s/\([^ ]* *\)\{2\}/\1 /g;s/^/ /'  \
>         -e'y/clayk/kieio/;G;t$' -e:$  \
>         -e'/^ \n /{s///;y/ \n/\n /;}' \
> -et     -e's/^ *\([^ ]*\) \(.* \n [^ ]*\) /\2\1/;t$'
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> can ccccc ccccccckkieiii sed clay ignore every kkieiii thing but the matching word - kkieiiikkieiii
> ```
>
> ...it isn't easy, though.

That one loops a little bit, too, but not nearly as much.

> As is true of most complicated problems, though, it is *way* easier if you use two `sed`s:
>
> ```sh
> echo can ccccc ccccccccclayii sed clay ignore \
>      every cclayii thing but the matching word\
>      - cclayiicclayii |
> sed -e's/\(cclayii\)\1*/\n&\n /g;G;s/^/ /'|
> sed -e'/^ /!y/clayk/kieio/;/./{H;d;}' \
>     -e'x;s/\n \{0,1\}//g'
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> can ccccc ccccccckkieiii sed clay ignore every kkieiii thing but the matching word - kkieiiikkieiii
> ```

With a BSD `sed` you'll want to use a literal newline in place of the `n` in the `\n` escapes in the right-hand substitution for the first `sed` there.