# Can sed `y` commands be applied only to matching text (instead of to the entire line)

Tags: text-processing, sed

After writing this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246723/sed-entire-word-with-bsd-sed/246727#246723), I did some googling to find out if I could make the sed `y//` command be applied only to the match and not to the entire line.  I wasn't able to find anything relevant.

```sh
$ echo clayii | sed -e '/clayii/ y/clayk/kieio/'
kieiii
```

In other words, if the search word (clayii) is just one of many words in the input line, I want the `y//` command to be applied **only** to that word and not to the remainder of the line.

i.e. I don't want this:

```sh
$ echo can sed ignore everything but the matching word - clayii | 
    sed -e '/clayii/ y/clayk/kieio/'
ken sed ignore everithing but the metkhing word - kieiii
```

Is that possible in `sed`?  or do i need to use something more capable like `perl`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the `y` command applies to all matching characters in the pattern space. Per the POSIX [`sed` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) (emphasize mine):

```
[2addr]y/string1/string2/
             Replace all occurrences of characters in string1
             with the corresponding characters in string2.
```

[OSX/BSD `man`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html) page:

```
[2addr]y/string1/string2/
             Replace all occurrences of characters in string1 in the pattern
             space with the corresponding characters from string2.
```

and [`GNU sed info`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands) page:

```
y/source-chars/dest-chars/
             Transliterate any characters in the pattern space which match any of
             the source-chars with the corresponding character in dest-chars.
```

Sure, you could use the hold buffer to save current pattern space then retain only the match, transliterate and restore the pattern space replacing the initial match with the result e.g. compare

```
sed 'y/words/evles/' <<<'words whispered by the drows'
```

with

```
sed 'h;s/.*\(drows\).*/\1/;y/words/evles/;G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)drows\(.*\)/\2\1\3/' <<<'words whispered by the drows'
```

but as soon as you start adding patterns/requirements it gets complicated.

Answer (score 2):

The perl: `perl -pe 's{(clayii)}{ ($new=$1) =~ tr/clayk/kieio/; $new }e' file`

Comment: +1 , nice.  you should post that as an answer to the question that prompted my Q.

Comment: Or simply: `perl -pe 's{clayii}{$& =~ y/clayk/kieio/r}eg'` (you may need a recent version of perl for the `/r`).

Answer (score 1):

It looks doable - you just have to sort of shift-in/shift-out:

```sh
echo can ccccc ccccccccclayii sed clay ignore \
     every cclayii thing but the matching word\
     - cclayiicclayii |
sed     -e'y/ /\n/' \
-eh     -e's/\(cclayii\)\1*/ & /g;x;s// /g;s/^/ /' \
-ex     -e's//./;s/\([^ ]* *\)\{2\}/\1 /g;s/^/ /'  \
        -e'y/clayk/kieio/;G;t$' -e:$  \
        -e'/^ \n /{s///;y/ \n/\n /;}' \
-et     -e's/^ *\([^ ]*\) \(.* \n [^ ]*\) /\2\1/;t$'
```

---

```
can ccccc ccccccckkieiii sed clay ignore every kkieiii thing but the matching word - kkieiiikkieiii
```

...it isn't easy, though.

---

As is true of most complicated problems, though, it is *way* easier if you use two `sed`s:

```sh
echo can ccccc ccccccccclayii sed clay ignore \
     every cclayii thing but the matching word\
     - cclayiicclayii |
sed -e's/\(cclayii\)\1*/\n&\n /g;G;s/^/ /'|
sed -e'/^ /!y/clayk/kieio/;/./{H;d;}' \
    -e'x;s/\n \{0,1\}//g'
```

---

```
can ccccc ccccccckkieiii sed clay ignore every kkieiii thing but the matching word - kkieiiikkieiii
```